# Use method return value as parameter c++

Tags: c++, parameters

I am trying to learn C++ and am trying to make a simple game of TicTacToe.

I created a Board object. This object contains a multi-dimensional array to create the playboard.

I have created two objects of the class Player as well. Both objects contain the name and the symbol of the player. I created a method for a player object to let the player make a move. They have to put in an Y value and an X value. I want to use this value in a board method to change the multi dimensional array.

This is one of the methods to get an integer value of the spot the player wants to put their symbol:

```
int Player::PlayerTurnX()
{
int x;
cout << "Enter the x-axe number which column you want to place your " << _symbol << ". ";
cin >> x;
while (!(x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 3)) {
    cout << "Please enter a number between 1 and 3. ";
    cin >> x;
    return x;
}
return x;   
}
```

This returns an integer value, right? I have the same kind of method for the Y value (I don't know how to pass 2 values through 1 method, tried an array but couldn't get it to work).

Then my Board-changing method looks like this:

```
void Board::AddPlayersTurn(int spoty, int spotx, char symbol) {
    int y = spoty;
    int x = spotx;
    string symbol1 = to_string(symbol);

    _boardSpots[y][x] = " " + symbol1 + " ";
}
```

Then the only thing left is calling the methods. I want to use the X and Y methods as parameters for my board-changing method:

```
Board1.AddPlayersTurn(Player1.PlayerTurnY, Player1.PlayerTurnX, Player1.GetSymbol());
Board1.printBoard();
```

printBoard() is a simple method that prints it to the command prompt.

I get this error when trying to do this:

```
'Player::PlayerTurnY': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
```

And the same for the X value.

Any help would be appreciated!

Greetings.

Comment: maybe use `Player1.PlayerTurnX()`... it is a function you are calling!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `Board1.AddPlayersTurn(Player1.PlayerTurnY, Player1.PlayerTurnX, Player1.GetSymbol());` you do not have `()` after PlayerTurnY (I suppose, this is a typo). But to the compiler it looks like a different typo - compiler believes, you tried to get an address of the member function and forgot to use `&` in front of it. The reason for this is that before C++, in C people could get an address of the function just by typing it's name, so lot's of folks assumed it is the same way in C++ - and compiler is trying to help them.

Obviously, this is not what you want.

Comment: Damn that I didn't see that!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put the parentheses at the function calls of methods PlayerTurn

The compiler is interpreting your statements as if you were trying to obtain the pointer to member funtions PlayerTurnX and PlayerTurnY. That is why the error message did not point directly to the real cause.